# How does a question get bumped without any apparent activity?

Tags: support, bug

This old question [how-to-find-new-poles-for-old-tent](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/how-to-find-new-poles-for-old-tent) showed up in my list of questions. The list says "modified yesterday fred 1" but I see no apparent activity by anyone named fred or anyone else. What's happening?

Comment: The good news is you are almost to 2,000 rep and will soon be able to [see deleted posts and have access to other cool tools](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Hi! The answers have covered it, but here's another hint. If you click on "fred" and go into his/her profile, there's a message that says "Keeping a low profile. This user hasn't posted yet." Since the question shows that fred did modify it, that lets you know that fred or someone else deleted the post. Also, if I remember correctly, if a question was modified by a user that's a grayed out number, that means the user is no longer registered, and you can't get to a profile. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, Fred with a reputation of 1 posted a now deleted answer and it shows up as last modified by Fred. Not always, but given the new users rarely ever bother to edit their posts and a rep of 1 is usually a sign of spam or low quality, its a really good guess.

You need 2000 rep to see deleted posts.

Comment: But if the answer/edit was deleted, why would the question list not reflect this (by omitting the entry)?

Comment: @MartinF I think its so other users can check to see that things aren't mistakenly being deleted

Answer (score 4):

The user, "fred", wrote a new answer.  That's why the question was bumped to the top of the list.

It turns out the new answer was just a rant, and didn't answer the question.  Three users with sufficient rep, in this case Charlie, imsodin, and myself, apparently flagged it as "not a answer" (or maybe voted to delete it, I don't remember).  When enough users do this, the answer is deleted without mod intervention.

Since your rep is below 2000, you can't see deleted answers.  You can see the question bumped due to activity, but you can't see that activity in the question.  Here is what it looks like to those that have sufficient rep:

[image]

The pink background warns us that the post has been deleted.  I deliberately didn't copy the content of the post since it doesn't belong here, and I don't want to give "fred" a grandstand for his rant.